# Running a powershell script on a Linux server

Tags: linux

We wrote a powershell script (.ps1) that basically runs a snmpget and a nnmsnmpget commands. It works great on all Windows 2008 servers but can't get it to work for any Linux servers. Yes, it's run from one of our management servers, NNMi. Research here says I can use SSH, but that was 6 years ago. Is there a more up-to-date approach?

Comment: Well, first, you need to get Microsoft to port PowerShell to Linux...

Comment: Ask and ye shall receive!  This is now in beta 8 https://github.com/powershell/powershell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to ensure your Linux servers are CIM enabled and then use the CIM powershell cmdlets to interact with the Linux server remotely.  You can read more about it here:

[CIM Cmdlets for Non-Windows OS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/08/24/introduction-to-cim-cmdlets.aspx)

If you're new to CIM, as in this is the first you've heard of it, you'll want to familiarize yourself with what CIM is and how it works.  Then attempt to try the CIM cmdlets.